# Trying to Make Image Background Opaque

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, background-image

I am trying to make the image only opaque while keep the rest of the screen normal.

I have already tried a simple usage of opacity  (ex: opacity: 0.9;)

My current code looks like this:
HTML

```
<ion-content class='background' no-bounce>
```

CSS

```
ion-content.background{
    --background: url(../../assets/main_background4.jpg) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

I would like to just dull the image I am using as a background slightly, but currently the entire screen goes opaque no matter what I try. Is it possible to set opacity some way in the --background part?

Answer (score 0):

try following css:

```
<style>
  ion-content.background {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:300px;
  }

  ion-content.background::after {
    content: "";
    background: url('../../assets/main_background4.jpg');
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The image does not display using that and it does not opaque at all

Comment: try by removing z-index: -1; . It may appear that image is hidden.